# checking the time with Date.getSeconds() is not working

Tags: javascript, date

I'm using JavaScript to check the user's time every 600ms (so my code runs once a second, but the time is unlikely to shift due to deviation in the `setInterval` method). My code looks like this:

```
setCorrectingInterval(function(){
   needs_run = false;
   switch(date.getDay()) {
    case 1:
        if(date.getHours() == "8" && date.getMinutes() == "50" && date.getSeconds() == "0") {
          next = array.ItemA;
          needs_run = true;
        }
        break;

        [abridged, all other ifs and cases are identical except the times and days]
    }

    if(needs_run == true) {
        alert("foobar");
    }
}
```

(`setCorrectingInterval` is a custom function designed to correct the deviation from `setInterval` as much as possible)

My issue is that I never get alert("foobar"). I've used `console.log()` and done some trial-and-error, what I've narrowed it down to is the `date.getSeconds() == 0` call. I've tried using `(date.getSeconds() <= "5" && date.getSeconds() >= "0")`, to no avail. The desired outcome is that, in this case, at 8:50AM on Monday, I get an alert, once.

When I omit the `date.getSeconds()` call, it works fine and dandy.

Comment: Don't compare against strings

Comment: That changed nothing, and it works when I compare against strings without using `date.getSeconds()`.

Comment: Of course. The 600ms is because `setInterval` can deviate, and I want to make sure my code runs every second, but only once every second, hence I needed a value between 500 (only runs once a second) and 1000ms (runs every second). 600 was just a random pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that something with your setCorrectingInterval() function or the date variable is wrong. It works fine with new Date().

```
;window.setInterval(function(){
    var tDate = new Date()
    console.log(tDate.getDay(), tDate.getHours(), tDate.getMinutes(), tDate.getSeconds())

    needs_run = false;
    switch(tDate.getDay()){
        case 1:
            if(tDate.getHours() == "8" && tDate.getMinutes() == "50" && tDate.getSeconds() == "0"){
                //next = array.ItemA;
                needs_run = true;
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            //No need to compare to string
            //if(date.getHours() == "13" && date.getMinutes() >= "50" && date.getSeconds() >= "0") {
            if(tDate.getHours() == 13 && tDate.getMinutes() >= 50 && tDate.getSeconds() >= 0){
                //next = array.ItemA;
                needs_run = true;
            }
            break;
        }

    if(needs_run == true){
        console.log('foorbar') //alerts can be bad.
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Your code prompted me to look at the spot where `date` was being assigned. I was assigning it outside the loop, causing it to be improperly checked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, `date` is not what you expect it to be. I suppose the following would be more appropriate for your case:

```
var date = new Date();
switch(date.getDay()) {
    ...
```

You commented:

> setCorrectingInterval is a custom function designed to correct the
>   deviation from setInterval as much as possible

What does that even mean? What do you mean by "*correct the deviation from setInterval*"?

Comment: A bad explanation, I apologise. I meant that setInterval suffers from latency. [Here](http://www.andrewduthie.com/post/a-self-correcting-setinterval-alternative/) is a better explanation than mine, the code I used, and examples.

Comment: It's better we don't use the term *suffer*, otherwise it will appear as if it does not execute it's functionality as espected. The function passed to setInterval is executed after all other queued executions are completed. The only way to reduce what you called a latency would mean to check more frequently for the elapsed time, and that can only come at the cost of wasted CPU cycles.